# Eclipse Java How to objectify JPA database table

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, jpa

I have set up a JPA Database connection for my Eclipse Java project to a PostGreSQL database. I was wondering if there was a way to create a class for one of the tables without doing everything by hand.

Comment: This is exactly the purpose of JPA. Look for the @Entity Annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,you can use hibernate reverse engineering. Pretty much with some simple set up, it will generate java pojo class for you.

See:

http://javafws.blogspot.com/2013/04/generate-hbm-files-pojo-classes-in-eclipse.html

and

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/